# Ubuntu boots in read-only filesystem after upgrade!

Tags: boot, filesystem, recovery-mode

**I got a serious problem here:**

I recently upgraded to the Latest Version of Ubuntu. Now, I boot to my Ubuntu Partition, and I get a Low-Graphics error!

I boot to a Recovery-Mode to see what the Problem is. Then, I try to Fix any Damaged Packages, to run fsck but nothing solved the Problem.

Then, from the Recovery Menu, I open a Root Shell. I try to create a File and I understand that the Filesystem is Read-Only. Then, I run:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

and it Worked for that Terminal Session!

When I go back to recovery, I select to resume Boot Normally but I get the Same Error!
a
I also tried to Boot to my Root Shell again, remount as Read-Write and Start Gnome from there. It Worked! *(But the user is ROOT, and is quite Dangerous!)*

**However, I can't do all this proccess at every boot!**

Any Solution?

*(Note that when I try to create a new File in my Ubuntu Partition from another OS, I **don't get any Errors!**)*

Answer (score 1):

check your S.M.A.R.T.
looks like your HDD is failing

Comment: OK! I will try it...

Answer (score 0):

Try this: instead of using the Root shell to mount the filesystem in read-write mode, choose "Resume Normal Boot." This *will* mount your filesystem in read-write mode (it even warns you that it's about to do that,) and then it will boot normally.

Comment: I tried to do so. Still the same error Appears!

I can't Understand... I also tried to create a startup script to remount the HDD to Read-Write, but it didn't work...