# Filesystem corruption / Remounted as read-only

Tags: 14.04, mount, filesystem, disk, ext4

### Issue

1. Ubuntu-14.04-LTS (Server) installed.
2. It worked fine in the past year.
3. Now, whenever I try to install a package file-system crashes and remounts as read-only.

### Working on it

Trying to install a package (via `dpkg -i` or `apt-get install`) results in:

> EXT4-fs error: mb_free_blocks:1433: group 3, block 130894:freeing already freed block (bit 32590); block bitmap corrupt.
>
> Aborting journal on device vda1-8.
>
> EXT4-fs error: ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
>   EXT4-fs: Remounting filesystem read-only
>   EXT4-fs: Remounting filesystem read-only
>   EXT4-fs error: ext4_mb_generate_buddy:756: group 3, 8181 clusters in bitmap, 8185 in gd; block bitmap corrupt.
>
> fopen: Read-only file system
>   debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Read-only file system
>   dpkg: error processing package man-db (--install):
>    subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
>   dpkg: error: unable to create new file '/var/lib/dpkg/available-new': Read-only file system

The reason it mounts on read-only mode is because the default setting in `/etc/fstab`:

> UUID=[MY-FS-UUID]    /    ext4    errors=remount-ro    0    1

In `/var/log/syslog` I can find:

> EXT4-fs: INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
>   EXT4-fs: write access will be enabled during recovery
>   EXT4-fs: orphan cleanup on readonly fs
>   EXT4-fs: 3 orphan inodes deleted
>   EXT4-fs: recovery complete
>   EXT4-fs: mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: (null)
>   Adding 1046524k swap. Priority:-1 extents:1 across:1046524k FS
>   EXT4-fs: re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro

I tried using some of the solutions in the following:

1. [How to fix "sudo: unable to open ... Read-only file system"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197459/how-to-fix-sudo-unable-to-open-read-only-file-system)
2. [Ubuntu boots in read-only filesystem after upgrade!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/201088/ubuntu-boots-in-read-only-filesystem-after-upgrade)

by doing so:

- `mount -o remount,rw -t ext4 MY_DISK /`

mount: cannot remount block device MY_DISK read-write, is write-protected

- `blockdev -v --setrw MY_DISK`

set read-write succeeded.

- `hdparm -r 0 MY_DISK`

MY_DISK:
 setting readonly to 0 (off)
 readonly      =  0 (off)

### update 1

I can't access the disk. It seems that the system wrote to a place outside the disk and now it's corrupted. I made a QCOW image of the disk. I'm trying to run it as a VM, and analyze the corrupted image.

I installed `libguestfs` and I'm trying some analysis tools such as `virt-cat`, `virt-rescue` and `guestfish`.

My main goal now is trying to access and read the system logs.

### update 2

In order to access the image, I connected the guest image as a device on the host x86 (credits: http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/how-to-recover-fsck-a-qcow2-file/, https://www.scaleway.com/docs/connect-a-block-device-manually/):

> # fsck /dev/nbd0p1
>   /dev/nbd0p1: clean, 62744/983040 files, 447645/3931904 blocks

partition 1 is the os one. On partitions 2,5 I get errors from `fsck` - those are the extend and swap partitions, respectively.

> # mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt/crpt
>   # cat /mnt/crpt/var/log/*

... currently searching through the logs ...

### Help?

Any idea what might cause the system issue?

Comment: Better reboot in recovery mode and do a `fsck`.

Comment: can't reboot the machine in recovery - to do so, I have to edit the grub - but, the fs is read only :(

Comment: Can you boot a Live install e.g.  from a USB?

Comment: yes, and that would give me a root shell... sure... but I already have a root shell now.... I want to know what causes the disk crash... formatting and installing from scratch won't help since I need the info that is already found on this disk... thanks a bunch for your quick reply, though :)

Comment: You would have a root shell that could do a `fsck` without the disk being mounted. You now have a root shell that can't do a `fsck` because the disk is mounted (preventing repairs) or is not mounted (preventing access to the `fsck` executable).

Comment: I can't access the fs, not from a usb stick anyways because I can't change the grub menu... it seems that the system is writing to a place outside the disk image and so it has corrupted the image.... I've made a qcow copy of the image and I'm trying to run it as a VM

Comment: @Jos I managed to check with `fsck`, please see update 2 :) and thanks!